# how to install basemap in python(x,y)

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, pythonxy

I am just new in using `python(x,y)` and while trying to plot some map using basemap module, it seems that this module has not been installed yet, and also requires `GEOS` libraries (??).

I tried to install basemap using pip and easy_install of python(x,y), and both of them were resulting this error message:

> Downloading https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib-toolkits/basemap-1.0.7/basemap-1.0.7.tar.gz
>   Processing basemap-1.0.7.tar.gz
>   Writing c:\users\bunda\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-3bggpy\basemap-1.0.7\setup.cfg
>   Running basemap-1.0.7\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\bunda\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-3bggpy\basemap-1.0.7\egg-dist-tmp-gjqhra
>   checking for GEOS lib in C:\Users\bunda ....
>   checking for GEOS lib in /usr ....
>   checking for GEOS lib in /usr/local ....
>   checking for GEOS lib in /sw ....
>   checking for GEOS lib in /opt ....
>   checking for GEOS lib in /opt/local ....
>   error: Setup script exited with
>   Can't find geos library . Please set the
>   environment variable GEOS_DIR to point to the location
>   where geos is installed (for example, if geos_c.h
>   is in /usr/local/include, and libgeos_c is in /usr/local/lib,
>   set GEOS_DIR to /usr/local), or edit the setup.py script
>   manually and set the variable GEOS_dir (right after the line
>   that says "set GEOS_dir manually here".

Hoping so much there is a solution..

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python(x,y) project used to have a plugins page when they were hosted on google code.  I don't know what happened to it when the project moved to github.

Fortunately the University of Kent has a [mirror](http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/downloads.sourceforge.net/p/py/python-xy/plugins/).  There is a binary installer called [basemap-1.0.2_py27.exe](http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/downloads.sourceforge.net/p/py/python-xy/plugins/basemap-1.0.2_py27.exe) that installs basemap in a python(x,y) installation.

Hope that helps.